# Should only specific characters be escaped in UTF-8 XML?

Tags: xml

What is the correct way to store the following text in a XML attribute?

Text:

```
", à,é,è, <
```

Output 1 (all escaped)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <outline text="element" _note="&quot;, &#224;,&#233;,&#232;, &lt;">
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

Output 2 ([only XML specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) escaped)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <outline text="element" _note="&quot;, à,é,è, &lt;">
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

Are both of these valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are both valid, and equivalent. The main reason to use numeric character references is that they are less likely to be corrupted as a result of inappropriate transcodings.